# Help me get this DSolve function to work

Tags: differential-equations

I have the following differential equation:

```
initialConditions = y[1.2932903356525765] == 0.2156456748626416; 
neutronFraction = 
 Derivative[1][y][x] == (255*(12 + 6*x + x^2)*(E^(-x) - y[x]*(1 + E^(-x))))/x^5
myRule = DSolve[{neutronFraction, initialConditions}, y[x], x]
```

When I execute this, I get:

> `{{y[x] -> 2.8100676208616016*^-302* E^(765/x^4 + 765/(E^x*x^4) + 510/x^3 + 255/(E^x*x^3) +  255/(2*x^2)) +  E^(765/x^4 + 765/(E^x*x^4) + 510/x^3 + 255/(E^x*x^3) +  255/(2*x^2))* Inactive[ Integrate][(255* E^(-K[1] - (255*(6 + 4*K[1] +  K[1]^2 + (2*(3 + K[1]))/E^K[1]))/(2*K[1]^4))*(12 +  6*K[1] + K[1]^2))/K[1]^5, {K[1], 1.2932903356525765, x}]}}`

At this point, I'm lost.  What should I do with the 'K[1]' expressions.  They look like some constant of integration, but I've already supplied the initial conditions.  Is there some way I need to further constrain this solution?

Comment: The solution is in terms of an integral that cannot be computed.  You could use `NDSolve` instead.

Comment: Thank you.  It's really helpful to know I shouldn't keep on trying to get this route to work.